# I want to add new sheet to an existing csv file, but I dont know how to go about it

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to add new sheet to an existing csv file, but I dont know how to go about it. I already opened the .csv file and i can access each element. so i want to create a new sheet on the existing .csv file and populate the cells with the data from the previous sheet.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\Desktop\test.csv"));
        List<string> listA = new List<string>();
        List<string> listB = new List<string>();

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            //line = line.Skip(1);
            var values = line.Split(',');

            listA.Add(values[0]);
            listB.Add(values[1]);
            listA.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
            listB.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);        

            Console.ReadLine();    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: csv files don't have "sheets". that's an Excel concept, and csv files are NOT excel files.

Comment: I believe you are confusing CSVs and Excel files.  Although MS Excel can open CSVs that does not mean they are the same format.  If you want to create Excel files you should should check out this MSDN article:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to post this as an answer, even though it's kind of a non-answer.  CSV files are simple flat-text files that are comma delimited.  There are no higher-level concepts to this file type such as sheets, or cells, workbooks, or formulas.

Since they are just simple text files that are specially formatted, there is no concept of sheets.  Instead you can maybe create additional CSV files and name the files accordingly.

If you want to create Excel files, and have individual sheets you can use various libraries or the COM Interops to do this.

COM Interops are for direct connections to Excel natively.  Here's a [MSDN How-To for Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186(v=vs.80).aspx).  This allows you to create a special object that will allow you to use Excel's API even though it's not a managed API through the .NET Framework.

Here's an example on how to add a sheet in that situation:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

if (xlApp == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("EXCEL could not be started. Check that your office installation and project references are correct.");
    return;
}

xlApp.Visible = true;

Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet); //adds worksheet to our workbook
Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1]; //access that worksheet linked into the workbook

if (ws == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Worksheet could not be created. Check that your office installation and project references are correct.");
}
```

Another option is to use the [Open XML SDK for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx), which can be used for the new Office formats (.xlsx for example).  Personally, I've never used this library, but it's similar to Apache POI for the .NET Framework.

Comment: thank you so much.. so this not limited to only .NET framework from your response. It is .csv format thing.

Comment: @onyx Correct.  CSV is just a text file with data and a delimiter.  There's nothing special about it. A spreadsheet on the other hand is a special file type / system.